# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String' in DataReader.GetString()

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I was trying to add data from a database to a `ComboBox`.

```
try
{
    SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("select * from Category_Master", con);
    SqlCeDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        string name = dr.GetString(1);
        cmbProductCategory.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

What am I missing here?

Comment: What exception are you getting ?? try to use `Convert.ToString(value)` rather the `value.ToString()`

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: I changed to dr.GetString(1).ToString(), but error still the same.

Comment: @voo [`GetString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) returns `string`. Don't need `.ToString()` here.

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN On which exact line? What is the type of your second column?

Comment: Try selecting just the column you want, using `*` may very well end up getting the wrong column if someone changes the database schema later. I suspect you're not getting the column you're expecting, but an `int` column that is at that position.

Comment: Obviously, data reader's column with index 1 has a value, which type is `System.Int32`, not a `System.String`.

Comment: I also changed to Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(1)); but no change..

Comment: @Soner Gönül in the databse? it is nvarchar.

Comment: Why are you selecting *all* columns when you're only reading one of them? Just select the column you want - that will cut down on the possibilities of error to start with.

Answer (score 32):

Your column doesn't have the type `string`. Apparently it's `int`. So use:

```
dr.getInt32(1).ToString()
```

or even

```
dr.GetValue(1).ToString()
```

which should be more roubst to type changes in the database.

As some sort of general advice I try to follow at least:

- Select only what you need. This has mostly performance reasons *and* the reason that you have to state the column names explicitly, thereby getting at least a sensible error if you change your schema incompatibly.
- Access the fields using their names, e.g.

  ```
  dr.GetGuid(dr.GetOrdinal("id"))
  ```

  Such a thing can also be nicely solved by an extension method:

  ```
  public T GetFieldValue<T>(this DbDataReader reader, string columnName)
  {
      return reader.GetFieldValue<T>(reader.GetOrdinal(columnName));
  }
  ```

---

Side note: Including stack traces (or at least saying which line in your code the exception comes from) can be helpful to others trying to help you. As you can see from the wild guesses what the culprit could be. My guess would be that the stack trace looks somewhat like this:

```
SqlDataReader.GetString
YourCode.YourMethod
```

and that `GetString` looks more or less like this:

```
public string GetString(int index)
{
    return (string) GetValue(index);
}
```

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yes it is _zero-based_. That's why, when you say `GetString(1)`, it search on second column in his table.

Comment: yes, first column is ID and second column is CategoryName which in nvarchar

Comment: Exception is at this line, i checked. "string name = dr.GetString(1);"

Comment: when you are talking about robustness, you should also consider a `reader.IsDBNull(int ordinal)`-check before accessing it with an ordinal!

Comment: you forgot to add the `<T>` in your call of `reader.GetFieldValue`

Comment: Usually I would just assume that whoever uses the code would be able to fix such small problems, but given that they have problems with fixing `dr.["foo"]` already ... ah well.

Comment: ... ;) nevertheless, such small hints would vastly reduce the pitfalls, the OP might have to deal with ...

Answer (score 2):

Your column doesn't seem to have type int.
To avoid things like this, you can use the columnnames instead of indexes.

```
try
{
    SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("select * from Category_Master", con);
    SqlCeDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    while(dr.Read()){
        string name = dr["yourColumnName"].ToString();
        cmbProductCategory.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: that's not a valid reason!! with ordinal you can do typed things, like `GetString`, `GetInt32`... with the string-indexer you can access the `object` (untyped) value

Comment: Correct, but at least you know for sure which column you're addressing.

Comment: still no valid reason... `reader.GetOrdinal("myColumn")` gives an ordinal for the column i want to deal with - how can you be more explicit?!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Point taken.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following conversion:

```
  Convert.ToInt32(yourstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok OK. Its solved....

Here is the code..

```
        try
        {
            SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("select CategoryName from Category_Master", con);
            SqlCeDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read()){
                string name = dr.GetString(0);
                cmbProductCategory.Items.Add(name);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

I changed the sqlcommand to a single value and changed column number for dr.getstring() to 0.. it worked. Thank you guys for the help.. I expect more because i am only half way in my project..

Answer (score 0):

> **Use Column name in your query then specify that column name into the reader.**

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("select catg from Category_Master", con);
                SqlCeDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while(dr.Read()){
                    string name = dr("catg").ToString();
                    cmbProductCategory.Items.Add(name);
                }
```