# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, sql-server

**CODE**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select billno from tpdetail", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    while (reader.Read())
     {
        MyCollection.Add(reader.GetString(0).ToString());
     }
    textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;
```

I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Comment: Not enough information here... probably MyCollection expects an int instead of a string

Comment: duplicate its already has answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582256/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-int32-to-type-system-string-in-dataread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what is the **datatype** of your `billno` column in the `tpdetail` table?? If it's an `INT`, then you need to **read it** as an `INT` - not as a string ....

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    MyCollection.Add(reader.GetInt(0).ToString());
}
```