# exp erore : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

hi I wrote the code below for fetch data from database with ADO.net to show in kendoGrid 
in My webservice :

```
var result = new List<Timeline>();
            TimelineDB _TimelineDB = new TimelineDB();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                _TimelineDB.loadTimeline_bulk(result, currentUserName);
            });

            return result;
```

the code wrote in DB layer :

```
public GeneralDAL.OperationStatus loadTimeline_bulk(List<Timeline> ListTimeline_bulk, string id_user)
        {
            GeneralDAL.OperationStatus operationStatus = GeneralDAL.OperationStatus.OperationSuccessful;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Returnsp_tbl_TimelineLstShow_bulk(id_user));
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GeneralDAL.con))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Connection = connection;
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        try
                        {
                            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                                ListTimeline_bulk.Add(new Timeline()
                                {
                                    ID_Timeline_bulk = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(Timeline.Fildes.ID_Timeline_bulk)) ? General.DefaultValues.Numricguid : sqlDataReader.GetGuid(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(Timeline.Fildes.ID_Timeline_bulk)),
```

and many field
but when i debugging the exp eroe :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Whch line does the exception occur exactly

Comment: GetGuid(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(Timeline.Fildes.ID_Timeline_bulk)) is this where it throws the error ?
Have you tried making it a string ?

Comment: Does this help you ? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582256/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-int32-to-type-system-string-in-dataread)